# requests library is not sending gzipped payload correctly in POST request

Tags: python, python-requests

I have a server which accepts gzipped payload in POST request body. So, I am compressing my data with Python `gzip` library and sending the compressed payload with `requests` library. The server is returning 201 response, but later during processing, it is complaining that the message doesn't start with the GZip magic number. The server is doing this intermittently, so I am assuming it has something to do with how the client is sending data in chunks.

To verify that the server is actually accepting gzipped data, I created a Java version of the same code and sent the request. In this case, the server is able to process the data correctly.

I created a simple echo server and sent the same request, once from Java and once from Python. The Java client is setting `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` header and sending the payload whereas the Python client is setting `Content-Length: ...` header and sending the payload. As far as I can tell, both of them should work the same. I am not able to figure what I am doing wrong, and I don't know what else I can do to debug as I don't have access to the server config or logs.

This is the Python client code:

```
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/gzip',
    'Content-Encoding': 'gzip'
}

httpSession = requests.Session()
adapter = requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter(max_retries=3, pool_connections=5)
httpSession.mount('https://', adapter=adapter)

compressedData = gzip.compress(data=data.encode('utf-8'), compresslevel=1)
response = httpSession.post(url=..., data=compressedData, headers=headers)
```

This is the Java client code for comparison:

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost();
httpPost.setURI(new URI("..."));
CustomCompressionEntity compressionEntity = new CustomCompressionEntity (new StringEntity("something"));
httpPost.setEntity(compressionEntity);
httpPost.setHeader(new BasicHeader("Content-Type","application/gzip"));


CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
org.apache.http.HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
EntityUtils.consumeQuietly(response.getEntity());
```

The `CustomCompressionEntity` is a basic wrapper that creates a gzip stream:

```
public class CustomCompressionEntity extends HttpEntityWrapper {
    private static final String GZIP_CODEC = "gzip";
    public CustomCompressionEntity(HttpEntity entity) {
        super(entity);
    }
    public Header getContentEncoding() {
        return new BasicHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
    }
    public long getContentLength() {
        return -1L;
    }
    public boolean isChunked() {
        return true;
    }
    public InputStream getContent() throws IOException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
    public void writeTo(OutputStream outStream) throws IOException {
        Args.notNull(outStream, "Output stream");
        GZIPOutputStream gzip = new GZIPOutputStream(outStream){{def.setLevel(1);}};
        this.wrappedEntity.writeTo(gzip);
        gzip.close();
    }
}
```

Please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong or at least where I can look next.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a mistake from my end. I didn't stop the thread that is sending uncompressed data and the server is not able to handle compressed and uncompressed batches of data coming from the same client.